# Basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ formed by the products of basis functions for $L^2(\mathbb R^1)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $\{\phi_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a orthogonal basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{1})$.

Is it true that

> $\{\phi_{n}(x)\phi_{m}(y)\}_{n,m\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a basis of
>   $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$?

How could we verify this?

I've been looking through Rudin's PMA, but couldn't find any related theorems.

If it's okay, suggest a recommendation book or stuff.

Comment: Why would $\phi_m\phi_n$ even belong to $L^2?$

Comment: @zhw. $\int\int\phi_{n}^{2}(x)\phi_{m}^{2}(y)\ dxdy=\left(\int\phi_{n}^{2}(x)\ dx\right)\cdot\left(\int\phi_{m}^{2}(y)\ dy\right)=1$

Comment: What you mean is normally denoted $\phi_m \otimes \phi_n$ in mathematics.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the whole point, carry on.

Comment: It's true, use Stone-Weierstrass and Riesz Representation Thm.

Comment: It's an exercise in Folland, all of whose proofs are available online.

Comment: Oh, your lack of compactness adds a bit of complexity.  Use the density of the eventually-zero functions (whatever notation you have for them, e.g. $L^2_0$ probably).

Comment: @JohnSamples I found it. It's #61 on page 178. But, I am still in struggle.

Comment: @JohnSamples Stein's book also has a same problem, and it has a hint below. I think we don't need Stone-Weierstrass, and Riesz Representation Thm.

Comment: Oh you're right.  There is a more general version with some otherwise-junky $\sigma$-compact spaces that needs heavier theory.  The answer below looks good at a glance, tho Stone-Weierstrass might be cleaner still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orthogonality is easy; the issue is the density of linear span. For any $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$ we can approximate $f$ by a finite sum $\sum  a_m \phi_m$ and $g$ by $\sum b_n \phi_n$; then $\sum_{m,n} a_mb_n \phi_m(x)\phi_n(y)$ approximates $f(x)g(y)$. So the problem boils down to showing that the linear span of functions of the form $f(x)g(y)$, with $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$, is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. This linear span is usually denoted $L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$, the tensor product of two vector spaces.

Observe that the characteristic function of any rectangle $[a,b]\times[c,d]\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$, being the product $\chi_{[a,b]}(x)\chi_{[c,d]}(y)$. Every open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a union of disjoint rectangles (except for their boundaries), for example one can take the union of all maximal dyadic squares contained in $\Omega$. This implies that $\chi_{\Omega}$  is in the closure of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$ whenever $\Omega$ is an open set of finite measure. An arbitrary measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ can be approximated by open sets from the outside, hence $\chi_E$  is also in the closure of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)\otimes L^2(\mathbb{R}^1)$. From characteristic functions we get simple functions $\sum c_n \chi_{E_n}$, which are known to be dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

For $f,g\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, functions $f(x)g(y)$ are in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. If $\{ \phi_n \}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\{ \phi_n(x)\phi_m(y)\}$ is a complete orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ by an application of Parseval's identity to $h\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Clearly $h(x,y)\phi_n(x)\phi_m(y) \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, which allows the use of Fubini's Theorem to prove Parseval's identity:
$$
    \sum_{n,m}\left|\iint h(x,y)\phi_n(x)\phi_m(y)dxdy\right|^2 \\
    =\sum_{n,m} \left|\int\left(\int h(x,y)\phi_n(x)dx\right)\phi_m(y)dy\right|^2\\
    =\sum_{n}\int\left|\int h(x,y)\phi_n(x)dx\right|^2dy \\
    =\int\int |h(x,y)|^2dxdy.
$$
You just have to be careful about a.e. issues.